# WPML integration with Mega Menu

Tags: wordpress, wpml, megamenu

I have to environments
1 is QA/Tests environment
2 is the production environment

The problem that I have is with the tests environment.

I am trying to make the two environment identical by taking a snapshot of the production environment and deploy it top the test environment.
They are suppose to be identical but there is something that doesn't appear in test environment,
in the production environment after opening to the admin side and clicking on Appearance > Menu (in the side menu navigation)[PROD ENV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sElQi.png) the marked elements don't appear in test environment [Test ENV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR09i.png)

What can cause that? something in settings that needs to be selected?

tried to look for differences of settings but I didn't find any..